# concat datasets in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a few datasets in folders, I am concating them using concat datasets. So, I have data folders like so (note that folders 1 and 2 only have 1 class rather than 2):

`-` denotes subfolders

```
folder0
-cats
-dogs

folder1
-cats

folder2
-cats

folder3
-dogs
```

and then I do this:

```
    trainset1 = datasets.ImageFolder(folder0, loader=my_loader, transform=SomeAug())    
    trainset2 = datasets.ImageFolder(folder1, loader=my_loader, transform=SomeAug())    
    trainset3 = datasets.ImageFolder(folder2, loader=my_loader, transform=SomeAug())    
    trainset = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset([trainset1, trainset2, trainset3])
```

Is this the legit way of doing this? When I look at the total images via:

```
len(train_loader.dataset))
```

it adds up correctly.

However, when I do:

```
print(trainset.classes)
```

it throws me:

```
AttributeError: 'ConcatDataset' object has no attribute 'classes'
```

which it does not when I use just one dataset.

I just wanted to ensure that there no gotchas in using thie concat dataset method.

Comment: cats and dogs in folder0,1,2,3 are subfolders or images?

Comment: @Phoenix subfolders - sorry should have been clear about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageFolder` inherits from [`DatasetFolder`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#DatasetFolder) which has a class method `find_classes` that is called in the constructor to initialize the variable `DatasetFolder.classes`. Thus, you can call `trainset.classes` without error.

However, `ConcatDataset` does not inherit from `ImageFolder` and more generally does not implement the `classes` variable by default. In general, it would be difficult to do this because the `ImageFolder` method for finding classes relies on a specific file structure, whereas `ConcatDataset` doesn't assume such a file structure such that it can work with a more general set of datasets.

If this functionality is essential to you you could write a simple dataset type that inherits from `ConcatDataset`, expects `ImageFolder` datasets specifically, and stores the classes as a union of the possible classes from each constituent dataset.